# How do I dynamically create options for a ReactJs dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask

I'm trying to update an existing React select (dropdown) to contain all of the users currently on a server. I have an array of all of the users on the server, I just can't get my dropdown to update when the array does.

Here is my code:

```js
class UserList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    socket.emit('join', {room: this.state.value});
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    alert('People on server: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    //not really using this
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  

  render() {
    return (
      <form onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite La Croix flavor:
          <select id="userlist" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            {this.props.list.map((name) => <option>{name}</option>)}
          </select>
        </label>
        
      </form>
    );
  }
}


class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login">
          <NameForm />
          <UserList list={users} />
          <Chat />
          <ChatInput />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm very new to React, and I don't understand how to get elements to update via external request (in this case a server). Right now, my javascript stores the list of people on the server in an array called 'users' that is updated by the server. I would like the dropdown to update whenever the array does.

EDIT:

Here is the code that populates the users array:

```js
socket.on('update_list', function(msg) {
  users.push(msg.data);
});
```

The users array is definitely updated after the server calls 'update_list'. I have printed the values in users after that is called, and when a new user logs on, users does update accordingly.

Comment: So, you pass the `users` array into the UserList. Can you post the code that populates the `users` array? Sounds like you are using `setState` on it incorrectly.

Comment: I edited my original post to show the little bit of javascript that populates the `users` array. I left out where I declared `users`, but it is globally accessible to both the react element and the socket functions. Could you elaborate more on using `setState`. I'm not sure on how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can't just add to a normal variable and expect React to magically know to re-render the virtual html, i.e `users.push(...)`.

[`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is the function you want. It will update the render methods of itself and it's child components after you call this function.

Your api call needs to be in a component.

For example, whenever the users change now it will update the render method because we use `setState` and it will re-render the new users.

Select doesn't have a value attribute. You want this on the option and probably want users to be an object. I'v updated the code.

This is just an example.

```
class UserList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    socket.emit('join', {room: this.state.value});
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    alert('People on server: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    //not really using this
    event.preventDefault();
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <form onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite La Croix flavor:
          <select id="userlist" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            {this.props.users.map(user => <option value={user.value}>{user.name}</option>)}
          </select>
        </label>

      </form>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.getUsers = this.getUsers.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        users: {}
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

    getUsers() {
        socket.on('update_list', function(msg) {
          this.setState({users: msg.data});
        }.bind(this));
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <UserList users={this.state.users}/>
    );
  }
}
```